# how to run e2e tests (angular-9) on a browser

Tags: angular, protractor, e2e-testing

I am working on an angular-9 application. Whenever I run my e2e tests, one of the tests fails . I wanted to run my e2e tests on a browser(chrome) such that I get a message on Chrome

```
Chrome is being controlled by automated test software
```

I looked at a lot of videos /articles but couldn't find a solution. My main purpose is to debug my e2e test

Here is the code for protractor.conf.js

```
const { SpecReporter } = require('jasmine-spec-reporter');

exports.config = {
  allScriptsTimeout: 1000,
  specs: [
    './src/**/*.e2e-spec.ts'
  ],
  capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome',
    chromeOptions: {
      args: [
        '--headless',
        '--disable-gpu'
      ]
    }
  },
  directConnect: true,
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4300/',
  framework: 'jasmine',
  useAllAngular2AppRoots: true,
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000,
    print: function() {}
  },
  onPrepare() {
    require('ts-node').register({
      project: require('path').join(__dirname, './tsconfig.e2e.json')
    });
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({ spec: { displayStacktrace: true } }));
  }
};
```

Comment: what is your question? how to run e2e? how to debug? what that message means? or why that error is happening?

Comment: I want to run my e2e tests on the browser so that I could debug them as one of the tests is failing.

Comment: You can consider debugging in Visual Studio code. Hope you have gone through my article.
https://medium.com/@ganeshsirsi/how-to-debug-protractor-tests-in-visual-studio-code-e945fc971a74